# No Such Column error in views

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I have created two views in sqlite - android , but when i create the second view 
i am getting error for

> No Such Coulmn : template_contact_info.tmp_text as text and
>   template_contact_info.tmp_link as link

even though both these columns are present in template_contact_info and  template_contact_view has been created successfully. but still dont know why i am getting No such column error.

Here is the code of views

First View

```
db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS 

template_contact_info AS 

SELECT

template_info.tmp_text as tmp_text ,
template_info.tmp_link as tmp_link , 
template_info.tmp_id as temp_id , 
template_info.tmp_type as tmp_type , 
template_contact._id as _id  
from template_info , template_contact 

where  template_info.tmp_id = template_contact.tmp_id");
```

Second View ***// here i am getting an error***

```
db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS 

template_contact_assign AS SELECT 

contact_info.c_number as number , 
contact_info.c_name as name ,  
contact_info.c_id as conid, 
contact_info._id as cid, 
template_contact_info.tmp_type as type , 
template_contact_info.temp_id as tempid ,
template_contact_info.tmp_text as text ,
template_contact_info.tmp_link as link 
FROM contact_info LEFT JOIN template_contact_info
ON contact_info._id = template_contact_info._id");
```

Comment: please post your select query...

Comment: select query of which table ?

Comment: query where you are getting this error.

Comment: @Hunt are you committing the transaction after the first db.execSQL statement? If not, the view doesn't exist on the DBMS so the second session won't recognize it (because you're creating a view on top of a view).

Comment: n how will i do that as m not committing any transaction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

//you are tying to get

```
template_contact.tmp_id
```

//while creating you are using `temp_id` instead of `tmp_id`

```
template_contact_info.temp_id
```

**Edit:**

DB is already exists so you need to uninstall/remove the database to create again for modified table.

Remove the database either by command utility 'adb shell`or via eclipse using the file explorer. The database resides in under`'/data/data//databases'`.

For `adb use rm <db_name>`

Comment: but i am getting error at template_contact_info.tmp_text and i have already renamed template_contact.tmp_id as temp_id so thts not an issue

Comment: uninstalling the app helped me !! thanks please update your answer so that i can accept it